# How to implement functionality of stepinfo in LabVIEW? Especially settlingMax and settlingMin?

Tags: matlab, labview

I am using both MATLAB and LabVIEW for Lab of course of control systems engineering and I want to implement a block diagram(system) in MATLAB and also in LabVIEW

[image: front panel]

[image: block diagram]

Front panel shows "time response parametric data" which contains 6 parameters fields including settling time ,but i also need **settlingMin** and **settlingMax** which are provided/shown in MATLAB by using command stepinfo but i couldn't find a way how to get these two parameters settlingMax and settlingMin in LabVIEW.

Here is MATLAB code

```
clc
clear all
close all
sys1=tf([10],[1 1])
sys2=tf([1],[2 0.5])
sys_series=series(sys1,sys2)
sys_feedback=feedback(sys_series,0.1)
sys=series(540,sys_feedback)
sys_cl=feedback(sys,1,-1)
step(sys_cl)
stepinfo(sys_cl)
```

[Download link LabVIEW VI](http://www.mediafire.com/file/6mv1nuqklm6niyr/Lab3_pre_lab1.vi/file)

Answer (score 0):

Comparing [the help for the LabVIEW VI you are using](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371894J-01/lvctrldsgn/parametric_time_response/#instance1) with [the help for the MATLAB function](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/stepinfo.html) it seems obvious that MATLAB's `SettlingMax` is the same as LabVIEW's `Peak Value` in the `Time Response Parametric Data` cluster, while `SettlingMin` is the minimum value of the time response signal after `Peak Time`.

To get the latter value it looks as if you need to:

- use [CD Get Time Response Data](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371894J-01/lvctrldsgn/get_time_response_data/#parent) to get the time points and response signal as `DBL` arrays - I assume `Input` and `Output` are both 0 since you have only one signal
- use [Search 1D Array](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361R-01/glang/search_1d_array/) with the time point array and the Peak Time value to get the array index of the peak time
- use [Array Subset](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361R-01/glang/array_subset/) to select the part of the response array from that index onwards (leave `length` unwired)
- use [Array Max & Min](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361R-01/glang/array_max_and_min/) to get the minimum value of this array